# Insert image with SQL

Tags: directus

I want to insert images into the `image field` of each `column`.

First, I move `images` to the `upload` folder of the Directus app.
Then I use the `SQL` query to insert the image name to each column.

I get this error:

```
invalid input syntax for type uuid
```

How can I solve it?

I use the latest version of Directus. My images are typed in slug style. Is there a way not to change the names of images?

I get this error when I type my image names as UUID:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid foreign key in field \"logo\".",
  "extensions": {
    "code": "INVALID_FOREIGN_KEY",
    "collection": "items",
    "field": "logo",
    "invalid": "3c676907-ab7e-4c20-9e77-63df89d7b2e4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show SQL query

Comment: Have you set up a foreign key for this list